# Selecting a value in a hstore results in "permission denied for function fetchval"

Tags: postgresql, permissions, hstore

I am using hstores in my database and having trouble with permissions. When logging in as a superuser, all works fine, but when using a "normal" login role, I don't seem to be able to select a value in a hstore:

```
mydb=> select properties->'foo' from t1;
ERROR:  permission denied for function fetchval
```

Selecting the hstore itself does work, so it doesn't seem to be a table-access permission problem:

```
mydb=> select properties from t1;
         properties         
----------------------------
 "baz"=>"foz", "foo"=>"bar"
(1 row)
```

I tried searching online for this error, but got zero results. Also, I cannot find the `fetchval` function in my function list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchval` is the function corresponding to the `->` operator on `hstore`.

Probably you have revoked the right to execute hstore functions from non-priviledged users.

For instance, if the `hstore` extension lives in the `public` schema, and you run something like that:

```
revoke execute on all functions in schema public from public;
```

then the users will have the right to select `hstore` contents but get this error message: `ERROR:  permission denied for function fetchval` when trying to apply the `->` operator.

To solve the problem, you probably need to revisit your security policy and handle differently the permissions on functions.

Comment: I might have done that yes once. I don't see that `fetchval` function, though. Can I grant/revoke access to operators too?

Comment: `\dx+ hstore` in psql would list all functions. Individually I think `grant execute on function fetchval(hstore,text) to public;` would work but you don't want to do that for every function I guess.

Comment: Also operators don't have their own permissions, they are essentially an alternative syntax to call functions.